# Flex return back the result after the event complete

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events

I have two functions in an ActionScript class, they are:

```
private function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
        _loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
    selectedBitmap = Bitmap(_loader.content);
}

public function byteArrayToBitmap( byteArray:ByteArray ):void
{
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler );
    _loader.loadBytes( byteArray );
}
```

Is it possible to send the selectedBitmap variable back to the `byteArrayToBitmap` function after the event completed?

Comment: Is your goal to have byteArrayToBitmap return the bitmap?

Comment: yes, I want the byteArrayToBitmap return the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you want to do.

You cannot return anything from the same call stack as the original call to byteArrayToBitmap, and there's no "sleep" available in AS3. Once you get into "loadCompleteHandler", you cannot return anything to the caller of byteArrayToBitmap. So you'll have to modify the caller to wait for the event COMPLETE and then check for the selectBitmap object. This will have to be stored somewhere.

That is, if  I understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Glenn.  You understand my question.  Actually, I think it is impossible, I just want to confirm it.